# passing arguments from one function to another in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have date value

```
  for(i=0;i<data['before'].length;i++) {
        var day = data['before'][i];               
        var dte = new Date(day);
```

I am trying to display the dates as a link in a div dynamically from java script. On clicking the link I am passing dte as object to `date_click` function.

```
$('#before_dates').append('<tr><td><a onclick="date_click('+dte+');" href="javascript:void(0)">'+dte.toDateString()+'</a></td></tr>');
```

On clicking the link the

```
function date_click(date){
    alert("Hi..."+dte);
}
```

I am getting following error:

**Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Source Code: date_click(Fri Aug 31 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (IST));**

I know its small error, but I could not figure a way to do that. Any help would be great.

Thank You

Comment: I guess you will have to wrap your date in doublequotes: `date_click('" + dte + "')`

Comment: +1 @KristerAndersson it should look like `alert("Hi..." + dte + "");` and `date_click('" + dte + "')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
'...date_click('+dte+')';
```

what you actually get is:

```
'...date_click(' + dte.toString() + ')';
```

i.e.:

```
date_click(Fri Aug 31 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (IST))
```

which is clearly not valid JS, hence the reported error.

You appear to be trying to pass the actual `dte` variable, and not its string representation.  For that to work you would just write `date_click(dte)` without any quote marks but this would only work if `dte` is a global variable (and those are bad!).

However you have jQuery, so don't use DOM0 "inline" event handlers when you can use proper DOM3 ones.  They cause quoting problems (as you have here) and also don't work unless the specified function is in the "global" scope.

Based on the updated question, use `data()` to bind the current object to the event handler.

```
function date_click(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var date = $(this).data('date');
    alert("Hi..." + date);
}

for (i = 0; i < data['before'].length; ++i) {
    var day = data['before'][i];  
    var dte = new Date(day);
    var $a = $('<a>', { text: dte.toDateString() }).data('date', dte);
    var $tr = $('<tr>').appendTo('#before_dates');
    var $td = $('<td>').appendTo($tr).append($a);
}

$('#before_dates').on('click', 'a', date_click);  // use event delegation
```

Note that this is quite verbose, now, but it's a clean way to build the required DOM elements.

Comment: Hi there i tried your answer but its giving me a particular date even though i click on different dates..

Comment: OK, but your question didn't show multiple dates.  Please update it to show how different date objects are supposed to result in different function calls.

Comment: Hi Alnitak i hava updated it ... I am using a loop to do that

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the quotes (hence that syntax error)

```
append('<tr><td><a onclick="date_click(\''+dte+'\');" href="javascript:void(0)">' ...)
```

Please follow what @Alnitak says, its a clean way of doing things.

Comment: actually, I don't think that's what he wanted.  I think he wanted to pass `dte` as a parameter, and not the _value_ of `dte`

Answer (score 0):

Attach the event dynamically with jQuery:

```
var row = $('<tr><td><a href="#">' + dte.toDateString() + '</a></td><td>');

$('#before_dates').append( row );

row.find("a").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Hi...' + dte);

});
```

That way you don't have to mess with various levels of interpretation of your string, it's much simpler this way.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to instead read the date string from the clicked element as opposed to reading it from the captured variable? If by some DOM manipulation, the date stored as the text of the `<a>` tag is modified, the click handler will still output the old date.

Comment: @AmithGeorge it rather looks like the OP is really trying to pass the actual date object, and not its string representation.